# Mercurial: are pre-commit hooks run for other committing commands than "hg ci"

Tags: mercurial

Are mercurial's pre-commit hooks also run for other committing commands, e.g. `hg backout` or `hg graft`? Since these commands do a commit themselves, I'd like to think this is the case but I cannot find it in the documentation anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes they do run for these operations: they run for every commit created on the local repo.
You can convince yourself that they run with a simple test like:

```
hg graft 10 --config hooks.precommit="echo 'hook ran'"
```

It will print `hook ran` when the hook is called